# Deleting a node from Binary Search Tree in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I've been trying to delete a node from a BST. I'm taking help of two functions where one (findInorderSuccesor) is being called when a node has two Children.
Problem is, the node that comes in as a replacement for the deleted node, is not getting deleted from it's original position. As a result, I've two nodes with the same value.

```
    obj.addNode(8);
    obj.addNode(2);
    obj.addNode(5);
    obj.addNode(1);
    obj.addNode(13);
    obj.addNode(10);
    obj.addNode(15);

    obj.deleteNode(obj.root,8);

    public void deleteNode(treeNode focusNode, int data)
    {
     if(data<focusNode.data)
        deleteNode(focusNode.left,data);
    else if (data>focusNode.data)
        deleteNode(focusNode.right,data);
    else
    {
        if(focusNode.right == null && focusNode.left == null)
            focusNode=null;
        else if(focusNode.left!=null && focusNode.right==null)
            focusNode = focusNode.left;
        else if (focusNode.right!=null && focusNode.left==null)
            focusNode = focusNode.right;
        else
        {
            //node has two children
            BSTDeletion obj = new BSTDeletion();
            treeNode replacement =obj.findInorderSuccessor(focusNode.right);
            focusNode.data = replacement.data;
            deleteNode(focusNode.right, replacement.data);

        }
    }
}



public treeNode findInorderSuccessor(treeNode focusNode)
{
treeNode preFocusNode = null;
 while(focusNode!=null)
 {
    preFocusNode = focusNode;
    focusNode = focusNode.left;
 }
return preFocusNode;
}
```

[image: BFS Traversal of the Tree]

Comment: you need to know the parent of inorder successor to be able to delete child. but you are saving the parent reference. Hence your code will never be able to delete node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Boola wrote, You need to know the parent of the node You are deleting.

When you say focusNode = null; you only make the reference null, you don't remove the object from the tree, because the parent is still referencing that node. 
You need something like this:

```
public void deleteNode(treeNode focusNode, int data)
{
 if(data<focusNode.data)
    deleteNode(focusNode.left,data);
else if (data>focusNode.data)
    deleteNode(focusNode.right,data);
else
{
    treeNode parent = focusNode.getParent();  // get the parent.
if(focusNode.left==null && focusNode.right==null) 
    {
        if(parent.left.equals(focusNode))
             parent.left = null;                //Set the parents reference to null. 
        else
             parent.Right = null;
    }
 else if(focusNode.left!=null && focusNode.right==null)
    {
        if(parent.left.equals(focusNode))
             parent.left = focusNode.left;  //Reassign the parents reference to the correct node. 
        else
             parent.right = focusNode.left;
    }
```

and so on.